# How do I use pcl::toROSMsg()?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a variable `world` of type `const pcl::kinfuLS::WorldModel<pcl::PointXYZI>::PointCloudPtr` and I would like to get it into a variable `cloud` of type `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`.

I am trying to use `pcl::toROSMsg` for this:

```
pcl::toROSMsg(world,cloud);
```

But I get the following error message:

```
pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/src/kinfu.cpp:234:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘toROSMsg(const PointCloudPtr&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&)’
pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/src/kinfu.cpp:234:30: note: candidates are:
pcl/common/include/pcl/ros/conversions.h:237:3: note: template<class PointT> void pcl::toROSMsg(const pcl::PointCloud<PointT>&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&)
pcl/common/include/pcl/ros/conversions.h:275:3: note: template<class CloudT> void pcl::toROSMsg(const CloudT&, sensor_msgs::Image&)
pcl/common/include/pcl/ros/conversions.h:308:3: note: void pcl::toROSMsg(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&, sensor_msgs::Image&)
pcl/common/include/pcl/ros/conversions.h:308:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const PointCloudPtr {aka const boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >}’ to ‘const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&’
```

How do I convert between these two data types?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62538/how-do-i-use-pcl::torosmsg()-?/) by [mankoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/4856/mankoff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the compile error messages, the problem is that your arguments are not of the right type.  The first argument expects a reference to a PointCloud, and you're passing a PointCloudPtr.  You just need to de-reference the shared pointer.

This should work:

```
pcl::toROSMsg(*world,cloud);
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mankoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/4856/mankoff/) on 2013-05-10**:
Hm. I thought I'd tried de-referencing it, but that does fix it. Thank you!